# How to calculate time/date difference between value and now?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently pulling data from an API, and get returned a date/time in a string in the below format:

`2020-08-27T13:26:11.983Z`

I'm guessing the string can be separated as such:

Date: `2020-08-27`
Time: `T13:26:11.983Z`

Though I'm not sure where the `T` and `Z` come into play?

How would I go about calculating the difference between the above string value and the current date/time?

The intended end result would be rendered in my React component as:

"`x` Hour/s `y` Minute/s ago"

Thanks so much in advance for your help everyone!

Comment: Also [ISO-8601 timestamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations).

Comment: T really doesn't mean anything. It is just a separator that ISO (forgot the standard name) standard required. Did you try converting the string to date and then trying date 2 - date1?